# How to print words and their frequency in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, twitter, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have a code which creates a bag of words from tweets and forms matrix of their frequency. I want to create a csv file which will have each word in my dictionary as column header and the rows will be the frequency of the word in each tweet.

Something like this:

```
        Word1  Word2 ..... Wordn
Tweet1    1     0    .....   0
Tweet2    0     0    .....   1

Tweetn    0     1    .....   0
```

But this format is not being achieved by my code, it is still giving me only the dictionary format. I am building a training dataset for svm.

code :

```
import operator
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('Twidb13.txt', 'w') as file: 
   file.write(json.dumps(sorted_words))
   file.write(count_vect.fit_transform(df.Text).todense())
```

I have words in sorted form as this  [["all", 0], ["cats", 1], ["in", 2], ["my", 3], ["row", 4], ["zzzpositive", 5]] and their frequencies as separately in a matrix format like this [[1 1 1 1 1 1]]. I want to combine these two.

Comment: where is your code then?

Comment: with open('Twidb13.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(sorted_words))
     file.write(count_vect.fit_transform(df.Text).todense())

Comment: please update your post not in comment

Comment: provide the input as well and also the imports that you used